# Is it required to program microcontroller with parallel port for the first time

Tags: microcontroller, pcb, microprocessor, 8051

In my company i have been told that when we are using the microontroller for the first time(factory sealed),it is required to program boot vector and other few parameters using the universal programmer(parallel port) to make it compatible for In system programming(ISP).

But as per user manual i understood that only when we are writing a custom bootloader for ISP at a different location other than the default ISP address then only we need to program that address to boot vector with parallel port device.

Can any one tell is it required to do that.

I am using NXP P89LPC954 Microcontroller(80CS1 based)

Comment: You mean 80C51.

Answer (score 1):

It is basically as you say.

The built in token ISP program supports programming the device through a default interface. This should then also allow, if I understand the datasheets correctly, to change all those parameters to change the ISP procedure.

However, this is a question you should ask inside your company, since it is much more likely the default interface(s) are used incompatibly on the end board. While you'd usually favour keeping one default interface available through the board, it is possible in this case that wasn't possible.

Comment: *"it is possible in this case that wasn't possible"* - semantically correct, but I still had to read it four times ;-)